# Distance Calculator

Tags: c#

I created a calculator in C# that displays the distance traveled based of user-input speed and hours traveled, and displays the distance to a list box expecting it to be displayed with increasing values, but the values calculated are just repeated. For example, I input 1 MPH  for 10 miles expecting the list box to display:

After hours 1, the distance is 1 miles.

After hours 2, the distance is 2 miles.

After hours 3, the distance is 3 miles.

After hours 4, the distance is 4 miles.

After hours 5, the distance is 5 miles.

After hours 6, the distance is 6 miles.

After hours 7, the distance is 7 miles.

After hours 8, the distance is 8 miles.

After hours 9, the distance is 9 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

but instead the list box shows:

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

After hours 10, the distance is 10 miles.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int hours;
    double distance;
    int speed;
    int count = 1;
    if (int.TryParse(speedTextBox.Text, out speed))
    {
        if (int.TryParse(hoursTextBox.Text, out hours))
        {
            while (count <= hours)
            {
                distance = speed * hours;
                distanceListBox.Items.Add("After hour " + hours
                    + ", the distance is " + distance);
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect value for hours");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect value for speed");
    }
}

private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `distance = speed * count;` rather than `distance = speed * hours;`?

Comment: change this line `distance = speed * hours;` to this `distance = speed * count;` this should solve it,

Comment: Spend some time and learn how to use the debugger. You can set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line to see what's happening and examine each variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `count` in your calculations instead of `hours`, and `for` is more practical than `while` in this case.

```
for (count = 1; count <= hours; count++)
{
    distance = speed * count;
    distanceListBox.Items.Add("After hour " + count + ", the distance is " + distance);
}
```